# Plot an ROC curve in R with ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, roc

I have two variables (Condition1 & Condition 2) for which I have calculated false alarm rates and hit rates and I would like to plot these on the same graph with separate curves for Condition1 and Condition 2. Both of these conditions have three points and both use the same false alarm rates. Here is what my data frame looks like:

```
measure <- c('False_Alarm','False_Alarm','False_Alarm', 'Hit_Rate_Condition1',
 'Hit_Rate_Condition1','Hit_Rate_Condition1', 'Hit_Rate_Condition2','Hit_Rate_Condition2',
  'Hit_Rate_Condition2')
point_on_curve<- c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)
percentage <- c(0.11, 0.1, 0.01, 0.80, 0.50, 0.20, 0.80, 0.55, 0.25)

ROC_data <- data.frame(measure,point_on_curve, percentage)
```

False alarms should go on the x axis, and hit rates should go on the y axis.
Please note that I specifically am not interested in ROC packages such as ROCR, but rather I think it should be possible to plot this using just ggplot.

Many thanks in advance!

p.s. Just to show that I have at least been trying something and genuinely don't want to get stack exchange to do my PhD for me, I've tried  recasting the DF and separating the two to make two plots as so:

```
 Condition_1 <- dcast(ROC_data, point_on_curve ~ measure)
 Condition_1 <- Condition_1[which(!Condition_1$measure == Hit_Rate_Condition2),]
p <- ggplot(data=Condition_1, aes(x=False_Alarm, y=Hit_Rate)) +     
  geom_point() +    
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, 1), col = "red") +
  expand_limits(x = c(0, 1))
```

This results in some absurd line which isn't a smooth ROC (not what I need), and I would still need to combine the two.... in any case, there must be an easy way to make this plot (which I need to do another 18 times) with the original DF in one go...

This is an example of how the curved line should be (I'm not looking for something aesthetically the same, just the same sort of curve!)
[image]

Comment: So did you try to plot this at all yourself using ggplot? Where exactly id you get suck? What specifically is your question that you are asking here? Right now it reads like a "please do this for me" post which is not the type of question we encourage here. Perhaps you can edit your post to clarify.

Comment: @MrFlick I've tried to plot two separately but they need to be on a single plot. I've been trying to figure it out all day... I'm guessing the problem my be something to do with how the data frame is arranged...I'm not sure what more info you need?

Comment: @MrFlick not fair, I'm completely stuck...

Comment: Well, if you made to separate plots and just need help combining them, show the code you wrote to make the two separate plots. Then it will be easier to see what you are trying to do.

Comment: @MrFlick done, but the separate plot is problematic and in any case there must be an easier way.

Comment: Checkout the [`plotROC` package](http://sachsmc.github.io/plotROC/) -- bottom of that page has curves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to reformat your data so that your x and y variables (the false positive rate and the true positive rate) are in separate columns and then use `geom_step`. Take a look at the code and output below and let me know if this is what you were aiming for:

```
ROC_data <- data.frame(measure, point_on_curve, percentage)

ROC_data = cbind(ROC_data[rep(1:3,2),], ROC_data[4:nrow(ROC_data),])
ROC_data = ROC_data[,c(3,4,6)]
names(ROC_data) = c("FP_Rate","condition","TP_Rate")

ROC_data
```

> ```
>     FP_Rate           condition TP_Rate
> 1      0.11 Hit_Rate_Condition1    0.80
> 2      0.10 Hit_Rate_Condition1    0.50
> 3      0.01 Hit_Rate_Condition1    0.20
> 1.1    0.11 Hit_Rate_Condition2    0.80
> 2.1    0.10 Hit_Rate_Condition2    0.55
> 3.1    0.01 Hit_Rate_Condition2    0.25
> ```

```
ggplot(ROC_data, aes(FP_Rate,TP_Rate,colour=condition)) + 
  geom_step() +
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,1)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

If you want to connect the points with a straight line, you can use `geom_line` instead:

```
ggplot(ROC_data, aes(FP_Rate,TP_Rate,colour=condition)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,1)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: many thanks for your amazing and swift response! This is almost exactly what I need and very elegantly done. Is it possible for the lines to be curved? (it would make more sense visually if the x-axis is reduced in size)

Comment: Instead of `geom_step` or `geom_line`, you could use `geom_smooth(method="lm", formula=y ~ splines::bs(x, df=3), se=FALSE)`. You may have to play around with the formula to get something appropriate.